# Bootstrap navbar brand can't place text on two lines and be responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a responsive bootstrap page, but when I tried to make it with code at the start (the navbar) I stucked. I have placed two lined text in the "a.navbar-brand", but it wouldn't center vertically and responsively. As I was searching for an answer there seemed to be nobody making it in a way, that it would work for me. I am looking for an answer, which is not made with paddings and margins, but with some responsive code. Please if anyone could tell me how to do that.

Here is my .png version of the navbar:
[Initial one](http://prikachi.com/images/513/8126513m.png)

And here is what I get with my code:
[Made with code](http://prikachi.com/images/515/8126515p.png)

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">KrasiStoyanov <small>Front End Developer</small></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">    
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'jaapokki_enchanceregular';
  src: url('type/jaapokkienchance-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('type/jaapokkienchance-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('type/jaapokkienchance-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('type/jaapokkienchance-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('type/jaapokkienchance-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('type/jaapokkienchance-regular-webfont.svg#jaapokki_enchanceregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-size: 16px;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
}
header nav.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #54c0b0;
}
header nav.navbar div.container-fluid {
  width: 72%;
  height: 100%;
}
header nav.navbar div.container-fluid div.navbar-header {
  font-family: 'jaapokki_enchanceregular';
}
header nav.navbar div.container-fluid div.navbar-header a.navbar-brand {
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.500em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
header nav.navbar div.container-fluid div.navbar-header a.navbar-brand small {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.650em;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

This is my code. Please anyone.. help me.

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheMetalMonster/bbvx30eu/)

Comment: You want the menu like in the first image?

Comment: Absolutely. Sorry for bad timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/844cegfx/1/)

**Three things that are incorrect for you:**

1. Your line-height for the `navbar-brand` was 1 which was causing it
   to align at the top.
2. Set increased padding for the each `li a` element in the menu.
3. Always write shorter code. You need not write CSS rule from the root
   element. Upto parent element is enough.

Comment: Is there a way that this menu could be 100px in height and there would be no need to play with the padding? I mean that I am looking for an alternative way (to be responsive) because if I want to place a query for the font-size to be smaller, then I would have to change all paddings and stuff.

Comment: Padding is by default in Bootstrap, I just increased it.

Comment: You can use the media-query for mobile devices for just the padding rules.

Comment: It doesnt work with brand Image. Could you please check why ? http://jsfiddle.net/cj6ab05w/

Comment: Are you still using Bootstrap 3.x.x? Please upgrade to the latest. 3.x.x relies on floats. CSS has advanced a lot since then, and the latest Bootstrap deals with flex box and grid.